# Can I heal my stealth bomber?

Tags: civilization-5

My stealth bomber is damaged, but it has no "fortify until healed" option and just letting it pass a turn without performing any action does not cause it to increase in HP.

Is there a way to heal the stealth bomber, and if there is, how is it done?

**EDIT** This question is now obsolete. From the latest patch (April 2011 patch, version 1.0.1.275) notes:

> Units: Add “Fortify until Healed” option for aircraft. Before, they only healed when inactive, which could cause confusion for the player.

Comment: There's the "self-repair" promotion, but somehow I doubt that's what you're looking for...

Comment: with ships, the fortify until healed option doesn't show up unless you're in your own territory. Have you put the bomber in your territory or in one of your cities and then tried to heal it?

Comment: @robertpateii stealth bombers can *only* be inside my cities...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They seem to have added the "Fortify Until Healed" option for air units in a recent patch.

Answer (score 9):

Even though there is no "Fortify until healed" option, your bomber will still heal. Simply select Sleep (F) and wait for it to heal.

<strike>You can also heal it by letting it sit on a Carrier. When it's on a Carrier it has the "Fortify until healed" option. To move your bomber to a Carrier use the Rebase command.</strike>

Edit: You are quite right about Stealth Bombers not being able to land on Carriers. It's right there in the manual! Sorry about that :-)

I've uploaded a video of a Stealth Bomber healing in a city:

Comment: I'm talking about *stealth* bombers. Stealth bombers cannot be stationed on carriers...

Comment: I have landed stealths on carriers before. I have a feeling that this is a bug in either the game or manual... the manual also says that you can't sack cities with the helicopter gunship, which definitely works. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is either put the Stealth Bomber to sleep or simply have it do nothing (by pressing the spacebar).  It will heal.